# how to create custom wm_copydata in mfc c++

Tags: c++, windows, marshalling, messaging

How can I create a custom windows message that passes any data to a different program.

I am messaging between a GUI-program and a server-program. My background is in *nix programming and I am a bit lost in the windows world.

Currently both programs are created by Visual Studio's wizard by chosing "MFC windowed application". Now I want an elegant way to communicate between the programs. Google gives me Cwnd->sendmessage + registering your own messages etc. However, I cannot pass a char pointer to a different program with standard custom messages (well, I can but the memory area is wrong, and the program segfaults). So, google again gives me sendmessage(WM_COPYDATA, hparam, lparam) which is marshalled. When googling marshalling... I ran into a wall.

I assume that marshalled messages (or their data) are passed into a shared memory area which is readable only by the sender and the receiver program (correct?). And by creating a custom message that has a pointer of marshalled data as lparam, I can pass any object to another program (correct?). How do I do this in practice? I tried the following:

```
pWin->SendMessage(pTargetWin, WM_CUSTOM_MESSAGE, pSourceWin, pData);
```

Above works if pData is integer. If pData is a pointer to object, I cannot use the object because of the missing marhsalling. I know that I can do a wrapper COPYDATASTRUCT wrapper to pData and change to WM_COPYDATA. Should I do that instead?

br,
Juha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WM_COPYDATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649011%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does marshalling for you, provided you've correctly initialized the  [COPYDATASTRUCT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649010%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that you're passing as the LPARAM (lpData is the pointer, not dwData). Custom messages won't do that, and you don't want to reimplement marshalling by hand. If you need marshalling, use WM_COPYDATA. Is that what you're asking? It sounds like you know the answer already.

If you need to support multiple different kinds of messages, you could just stuff an enum in COPYDATASTRUCT.dwData to specify what the rest of the data means. If four bytes isn't enough, you could define a header on your marshalled data.

One way or another, as long as you can pass a big pile of zeroes and ones, you can communicate anything you like.

Comment: Well, what I want is to do marshalling by hand... The other option is to use WM_COPYDATA as you said. The other thing what I want to know is the visibility of the marshalled data (in case of WM_COPYDATA). Is it visible to all programs or just the two?

Comment: Why do you want to do marshalling by hand? As for visibility, there's no security on that stuff, AFAIK. Spy++ can hook anybody's message loop and see whatever's there. Well... actually that's for two processes belonging to the same user. I doubt you could look at a message queue belonging to a different user account. But the former would be enough for something analagous to cross-site scripting.

Comment: This is the last piece of code for a large multiplatform, multiopsys software that I am working on. I am not so familiar with windows programming and I was just exploring the contradiction: "you can generate every kind of wm_message <-> you have to use wm_copydata". Anyway, it seems that the correct practise is to use wm_copydata and wrap the stuff in the copydatastruct. What I am going to wrap is a command pattern object. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237639/command-pattern-serialization-in-c Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ahh, I gotcha: Window messages are how the OS tells you about user input, and how you talk to child windows within your process. In Win32 historically (and behind the scenes in MFC, and even Windows Forms), if you want to add an item to a listbox, you send it a message (LB_ADDSTRING). If you want the count of items in the listbox, you send it a different message (LB_GETCOUNT). The word "message" got attached to the concept years before Windows had multitasking. The terminology is definitely misleading to somebody who hasn't been along for the whole ride. It's not an IPC mechanism.